# how to compare two array of objects in for duplicates javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays with objects such as arr1 and arr2 and i want to separate duplicate items and original items. I mean, from arr1, whatever the items are matching with arr2, then those items [from arr1] are considered as duplicates. if it is not matching, then, it is original items.

I did the below program, but, it quite not working as expected

```
arr1 = [{name: "sunrise.jpg"},{name: "nature.jpg"},{name:"sunflower.jpg"}, {name: "sunset.jpg"}];

arr2 = [{
            "@type" : "Image",
            "objectTypeId" : "Image",
            "baseTypeId" : "document",
            "name" : "sunrise.jpg",
            "width" : "284",
            "height" : "177"
        }, {
            "@type" : "Image",
            "objectTypeId" : "Image",
            "baseTypeId" : "document",
            "name" : "Lao Tzu",
            "width" : "638",
            "height" : "960"
        }, {
            "@type" : "Image",
            "objectTypeId" : "Image",
            "baseTypeId" : "document",
            "name" : "nature.jpg",
            "width" : "300",
            "height" : "168"
        }, {
            "@type" : "Image",
            "objectTypeId" : "Image",
            "baseTypeId" : "document",
            "name" : "replay_12",
            "width" : "500",
            "height" : "717"
        }, {
            "@type" : "Image",
            "objectTypeId" : "Image",
            "baseTypeId" : "document",
            "name" : "sunflower.jpg",
            "width" : "300",
            "height" : "168"
        }
    ];

var originalItems = [];
var diff = function(arr1, arr2) {
    var dupes = [];

    for(var i in arr1) {   
    //console.log(i);
         for(var j in arr2){
           if(arr1[i].name === arr2[j].name){
             dupes.push(arr2[j]);
           } else {
            originalItems.push(arr2[j]);
           }
         }       
    }
    return dupes;
}   

var sd = diff(arr1, arr2);

console.log(sd);
console.log(originalItems);
```

Here, original items have 'sunset.jpg' and rest are moved to 'dupes'.

Am missing something here, any clue, pls?

Comment: What do you expect as result from the example above?

Comment: I jus copied and pasted your code in a jsfiddle and the result is not the one you say. I get dupes = sunrise, nature, sunflower; and the rest in originals. I did nothing, just copy & paste

Comment: @Kinduser actually, you're right, it doesn't work, the "originalItems" array has all items. But the result is deffinitely not the one from the question. But yeah, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array#some` and `Array#every` to determine if `arr1` contains given element or not and filter it with `Array#filter`.

```js
var arr1 = [{name: "sunrise.jpg"},{name: "nature.jpg"},{name:"sunflower.jpg"}, {name: "sunset.jpg"}],
    arr2 = [{"@type":"Image","objectTypeId":"Image","baseTypeId":"document","name":"sunrise.jpg","width":"284","height":"177"},{"@type":"Image","objectTypeId":"Image","baseTypeId":"document","name":"Lao Tzu","width":"638","height":"960"},{"@type":"Image","objectTypeId":"Image","baseTypeId":"document","name":"nature.jpg","width":"300","height":"168"},{"@type":"Image","objectTypeId":"Image","baseTypeId":"document","name":"replay_12","width":"500","height":"717"},{"@type":"Image","objectTypeId":"Image","baseTypeId":"document","name":"sunflower.jpg","width":"300","height":"168"}], 
    dupes = arr2.filter(v => arr1.some(c => c.name == v.name)),
    originals =  arr2.filter(v => arr1.every(c => c.name != v.name));
    
    console.log(dupes);
    console.log(originals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `checkDuplicates` will return object `{}` with two arrays in it, first duplicates and second nonduplicates.

```js
function checkDuplicates(array, compareWith) {
   var nonDuplicates = [];
   var duplicates = [];
   
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var element = array[i];
    var isDuplicate = false;
    
    for (j = 0; j < compareWith.length; j++) {
    
      var comparedElement = compareWith[j];
      
      if (element.name === comparedElement.name) {
        isDuplicate = true;
        duplicates.push(comparedElement);
      }
      
    }
    
    if (!isDuplicate) {
      nonDuplicates.push(element);
    }
  
  }
  //ES6 would be
  //return  { duplicates, nonDuplicates };  
  return {duplicates: duplicates, nonDuplicates: nonDuplicates };


}

var arr1 = [{name: "sunrise.jpg"},{name: "nature.jpg"},{name:"sunflower.jpg"}, {name: "sunset.jpg"}];

var arr2 = [{
            "@type" : "Image",
            "objectTypeId" : "Image",
            "baseTypeId" : "document",
            "name" : "sunrise.jpg",
            "width" : "284",
            "height" : "177"
        }, {
            "@type" : "Image",
            "objectTypeId" : "Image",
            "baseTypeId" : "document",
            "name" : "Lao Tzu",
            "width" : "638",
            "height" : "960"
        }, {
            "@type" : "Image",
            "objectTypeId" : "Image",
            "baseTypeId" : "document",
            "name" : "nature.jpg",
            "width" : "300",
            "height" : "168"
        }, {
            "@type" : "Image",
            "objectTypeId" : "Image",
            "baseTypeId" : "document",
            "name" : "replay_12",
            "width" : "500",
            "height" : "717"
        }, {
            "@type" : "Image",
            "objectTypeId" : "Image",
            "baseTypeId" : "document",
            "name" : "sunflower.jpg",
            "width" : "300",
            "height" : "168"
        }
    ];
    
console.log(checkDuplicates(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = ...;
var arr2 = ...;

function diff(arr1, arr2) {
    var dupes = [],
        originalItems = [];

    arr2.forEach(function(o2) {               // for each object o2 in arr2
        var test = arr1.some(function(o1) {   // check if there is some object from arr1 that has the same name
            return o1.name === o2.name;
        });
        if(test)                              // if there is
            dupes.push(o2);                   // then push it into the dupes array
        else                                  // if not
            originalItems.push(o2);           // then it is an original
    });

    return {                                  // return like this is much organized
        dupes: dupes,
        originalItems: originalItems
    };
}   

var res = diff(arr1, arr2);                    // the result is an object containing two arrays: the dupes one and the originalItems one

console.log(res.dupes);
console.log(res.originalItems);
```